# Trouble with first time motion tracking

Tags: motion-capture

I'll be concise:

1. while I can get to motion tracking I don't have the same menus I see on specific tutorials that seem to be running 2.8.  odd.
2. I can Ctrl+A and place markers all over.
3. I cannot get them to track and show tracers when scrubbing left or right, regardless of which track button I'm using (command T, or Shift command T).

Everyone seems to have a menu next to "help" that shows motion tracking as an option.  I've got nothing but tabs up there (layout, modeling, sculpting, UV editing, etc).

Comment: Hi welcome! You should perhaps investigate (eg: ask the author) which version was used to create that tutorial you're referring to, then use that exact same version (download that version from the release repository - https://download.blender.org/release/ - and run it from it extracted folder). When you understand the tutorial workflow, using another newer version could just need to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to access the layout for tracking is to create a new project: File->New->VFX.

[image]

It should open with all the windows you need for motion tracking.

[image]

To display the paths for tracking marks Open Clip Display and enable Marker Display-> Path

[image]